# How to define function in TypeScript with a destrcutured array as parameter

Tags: function, typescript, parameters

I'm new to TS, but am very experienced in the latest on JavaScript. I'd like to use features that I'm familiar with in ES6. One in particular is using array destructuring in a function's parameters. I've learned that you can use an `interface` in TS to do object destructuring like so:

```
interface FooParameters {
  bar: any
}

function foo ({ bar }: FooParameters) {
  console.log(bar)
}

foo({ bar: 'fizz' })
// logs "fizz"
```

But I can't seem to find documentation on converting the following JS to TS

```
function foo ([bar]) {
  console.log(bar)
}

foo(['fizz'])
// logs "fizz"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function foo(...barArray: FooParameters[]) {}
```

Comment: It's unclear to me how a spread operator here would give me access to the parameter bar. Wouldn't this allow several variables to put into an array? I want to take a variable out of one.

Comment: In this case, ... is concidered to be a "rest" operator (https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/12/23/typescript-2-1-object-rest-and-spread).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I got it to work but I had to do the following to get it to work.  You might want to edit your answer to clarify

    function bar([bar]: FooParameters[]) {
      console.log(bar)
    }

Comment: interesting; so you do not need FooParameters, correct?

Otherwise you will need to use:
    let a = ['fizz'].map<FooParameters>((v) => ({ bar: v })); 
    foo(...a);

Comment: I was mistaken this doesn't work in either way. I was testing with already compiled code, but trying to use the function in the way described before compiling it breaks compilation

Comment: It seems like the correct answer is `function foo([bar]: [string)) {}`

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with advice from @bnieland I was able to surmise the right answer. I needed to define an inline tuple with the corresponding parameters and their types.

```
function foo ([bar]: [string]) {
  console.log(bar)
}

foo(['fizz']) // logs "fizz"
```

Comment: I have never seen that construct for an array (i.e. `function foo ([bar]: [string])`).  Is it any different than `function foo ([bar]: [string])`?

Comment: fyi: I am sure you are aware, but [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) is an excellent place to try out these pure language questions!

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But could you clarify your first response? Those two declarations look the same to me

Comment: Oops! You are correct!  Here is what I meant!   `function foo ([bar]: [string])` vs. `function foo ([bar]: string[])`

Comment: Sorry, I've been digging a bit deeper, and I realized that `function foo ([bar]: string[])` does work for the above code. I also, realized this example I gave didn't address my problem because I was trying to destructure two parameters from the array and they were different types, which is why I needed the tuple

Comment: Not sure if that is possible, at least in a clean way.